# How to get a list/result of best selling items

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the results of my best selling products using SQL.

My table is `order_items` which has the following columns.

```
id|product_id|qty
```

As there is a `QTY` field I have to somehow count or group each by product ID then sum the qty, then only return the top 5 selling items.

So the data looks kind of like below.

```
id|product_id|qty
-------------------------
 1|   1      |   1
 2|   1      |   3 
 3|   2      |   3 
 4|   2      |   1 
 5|   1      |   7
```

... and so on

Not to sure about how to go about this, any help is much appreciated.

Database system used is MySQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, I might use:

```
SELECT TOP(5) ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM order_items
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC;
```

This returns the top 5 best-selling Products.

Since `SUM(Quantity)` is also included in the SELECT clause, you can reference its alias in ORDER BY instead of repeating the expression:

```
...
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC;
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(qty) AS TotalQuantity
FROM order_items
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Here's [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ba4/5)**

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(qty) AS TotalQuantity
FROM order_items
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(qty) DESC
LIMIT 10
```